# Streaming video from xampp, which way?

Tags: android, video

Ok, So I'm trying to learn how to stream video for the first time but I have some questions as there is a lot of info out there on the android side, some old etc and not very many tutorials on the whole process as far as server side.  First, what is the difference between these two methods for streaming a video off xampp?  These seem to be the two most common answers I find for video on android.  The first seems very Picasso like, send a URL and boom get your video.  Very easy. The Retrofit is more involved but I don't know the reasons why I would go that route, much like I don't use retrofit to get my images.
Can anyone explain to me the difference here so I'm doing this the right way.

```
String url = "http://yourvideo/url/video.mp4";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
   myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url));
   myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
   myVideoView.requestFocus();
   myVideoView.start();
}
}
```

and a retrofit stream like so.

```
interface Service {
@GET("path/to/your/resource")
@Streaming
Call<ResponseBody> getData();
}


Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getData();
try {
InputStream is = call.execute().body().byteStream();
(...)
} catch (IOException e) {...}
```

Comment: first one loads the video URL into the videoView. Second one opens the stream to manually process it. So basically they have nothing relative, everithing is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **first method** you are directly parsing the remote URL through the **"videoView"**

In the **second method** **"Retrofit"** library is used where we can easily translate the **REST APIs** to Java Interfaces.

Retrofit can be used as the best alternative to **Volley**.

Retrofit Uses **OkHttp** for making HTTP requests.

**NOTE:**

My suggestion is that you can use **"Exoplayer"** for streaming videos from servers where it supports features like Dynamic adaptive streaming over HTTP (DASH), SmoothStreaming with Custom Design

[Please refer this link](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/exoplayer-intro/#0)

Happy Coding!!

Comment: Thanks.  That whole Step 2.  Importing the project and cloning it.  I have never really had to do any of that before.  Is that even necessary.  Can I simply implementation in my gradle?  Also does Exoplayer lag like the android video view from android off the URL?  I just read a thing by instagram saying they solved that with a proxie server ect... way out of my resources league.  I'm just curious if any streaming done will lag of xampp.

Comment: I understand your problem..please refer the link which i sent you because you no need to import the project or clone it while using "Exoplayer" library. The only thing you need to do is to add dependencies in your gradle file. Also as per your asked "Exoplayer" will not lag like android video view since it supports multiple formats over dynamic adaptive streaming.

Comment: Note: In the link they have imported the existing project from github..you can start from phase 3 "Stream"

Comment: Okay happy coding..mark my answer if it's useful for you

Comment: I has been useful,  I been using their main site. https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/guide.html#creating-the-player.

Comment: I was crashing but I figured it out, i needed to move the setPlayer to the end.  This works much better thank you very much.  Now that I got this down. I'm off to learn how to stream off an IP cam.  I swear the more you learn the easier this stuff gets.

Comment: I do have one question though.  why does my back button not work LOL  It crashes me.  But if I comment out the player, it works no problem

Comment: post your logcat i'll help if possible

Comment: Thanks, I think I have it now.  I'm not sure what the issue was, I switched the context around as I had declared a context for retrofit to set a spinner adapter and for some reason, activity.this was no longer being accepted as the context in the intent, but only while the code for Exoplayer was there, if commented out, the intent worked fine.  So weird.